# How to re-index documents in Solr without knowing last modified time?

Tags: solr

How to handle the following scenario in Solr's `DataImportHandler`? We do a full import of all our documents once daily (the full indexing takes about 1 hour to run). All our documents are in two classes, say A and B. Only 3% of the documents belong to class A and these documents get modified often. We re-index documents in class A every 10 mins via deltaQuery by using the modified time. All fine till here.

Now, we also want to re-index **ALL** documents in class A once every hour (because we have a view_count column in a different table and the document modified time does not change when we update the view_count). How to do this?

Update (short-term solution): For now we decided to not use the modified time in the delta at all and simply re-index all documents in class A every 10 mins. It takes only 3 mins to index class A docs so we are OK for now. Any solution will be of help though.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using separate query an deltaQuery parameters in your DIH DB config, I chose to follow the suggestion found [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandlerDeltaQueryViaFullImport), which allows you to use the same query logic for both full and partial updates by passing different parameters to Solr to perform either a full import or a delta import.

In both cases, you would pass ?command=full-import, but for a full import you would pass &clean=true as a URL parameter, for a delta you would pass &clean=false, which would affect the # of records returned from the query as well as tell Solr whether or not to flush and start over.

Comment: Mike, it looks like your solution gives only two possible execution scenarios? I need three.

Answer (score 0):

I found one can use `ExternalFileField` to store the view count and use a function query to sort the results based on that field. (I asked another question about this on SO: [ExternalFileField in Solr 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015049/externalfilefield-in-solr-3-6/12018587).)  However, I found that these fields cannot be returned in the Solr result set, which meant I needed to do a DB call to get the values for the fields. I don't want to do that.

Found an alternate solution: When trying to understand Mike Klostermeyer's answer, I found that `command=full-import` can also take an additional query param: `entity`. So now I set up  two top-level entities inside the `<document>` tag in `data-config.xml` - the first one will only index docs in class A and the second one will only index docs in class B. For class A documents we do a delta import based on last modified time every 5 mins and a full import every hour (to get the view_count updated). For class B documents, we only do one full import every day and no delta imports.

This essentially gives three different execution plans to run at different time intervals.

There is also one caveat though: need to pass query param `clean=false` every time I run the import for an entity; otherwise the docs in the other entity get deleted after indexing completes.

One thing I don't like about the approach is the copy-pasting of all the queries and sub-entities from one top entity to the other. The only difference between the queries in the top-level entities is whether the doc is in class A or class B.